# Usage of $ref in json schema file

Tags: rest, mule, raml

I have a folder named schema having employee.schema file.

In the code snippet below address attribute is an array type.

I want to have address.schema file in the same folder where employee.schema is kept and refer it in employee.schema

Is this possible with draft-03 schema?

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "properties":{
        "empId":{
            "type":"integer",
            "required":false
         },
         "empName":{
            "type":"string",
            "required":true,
            "minLength":10,
            "maxLength":20
         },
         "contactno":{
            "type":"string",
            "required":true,
            "minLength":10,
            "maxLength":10
          },
          "salary":{
            "type":"integer",
            "required":true
          },
          "address":{
            "type":"array",
             "items":{
                "type": "object",
                 "properties": {
                    "city":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "required":true
                        },
                    "pincode":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "required":true
                     }
                 }  
            }
          }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the draft-03 spec says it all:

> This attribute defines a URI of a schema that contains the full
> representation of this schema.  When a validator encounters this
> attribute, it SHOULD replace the current schema with the schema
> referenced by the value's URI (if known and available) and re-
> validate the instance.  This URI MAY be relative or absolute, and
> relative URIs SHOULD be resolved against the URI of the current
> schema.

(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03#section-5.28)

Simply define "address" as a "$ref" that points to that other schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "properties": {
    "empId": {
      "type": "integer",
      "required": false
    },
    "empName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "minLength": 10,
      "maxLength": 20
    },
    "contactno": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "minLength": 10,
      "maxLength": 10
    },
    "salary": {
      "type": "integer",
      "required": true
    },
    "address": {
      "$ref": "address.schema"
    }
  }
}
```

and then "address.schema" would look like this:

```
{
  "type":"array",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",       
   "items": {
      "type": "object",
       "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type":"string",
            "required":true
          },
          "pincode": {
            "type":"string",
            "required":true
          }
       }
    }
}
```